# Can't pass an iterator to a function which accepts pointer

Tags: c++

In "Effective STL" tip 16, it says that we should avoid to pass iterator to a function which accepts a pointer. Could anyone explain the detail for me please?

```
void doSomething(const int* pInts, size_t numInts);
vector<int> v;
...
doSomething(&v[0],v.size()) //correct
doSomething(v.begin(),v.size()) //incorrect
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In some early implementations of the standard library iterators were implemented as pointers.

Code that depended on that property stopped working when iterators became non-pointers.

So, you should not pass an iterator where a pointer is expected, because if it compiles then it's just by happen-chance. An iterator is not necessarily a pointer. And if it is a pointer, then it may not necessarily be a pointer in some later version (of the library, compiler, whatever).

Comment: Vector iterators are often pointers in release mode. If you pass an iterator to a function accepting a pointer, you get code that compiles in release mode but fails to compile in debug mode :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: arguably therefore what they *should* be is trivial wrappers to a pointer, to avoid that inconsistency.

Comment: Not just for the inconsistency, pointers don't have `std::` as their associated namespace.

Comment: @MSalters: interesting point, should implementations put their iterators in a different namespace, to prevent programs from incorrectly relying on `std` being associated?

Comment: @Steve: deeper question, should one in general design things to be "ADL-safe"? I think it would be difficult!

Comment: @Alf: Agreed, it's difficult to cover everything. "One" has an advantage over standard library implementers, though, that if I feel like it I can just *guarantee* that my own containers' iterators are (or aren't) in the same namespace as the container. Then I don't need to help my users with their ADL-safety, because if they accidentally assume it, it's OK. Certainly implementations can't make *every* perverse or surprising choice permitted by the standard, so I suppose this is at most a "might help users if" rather than a "should".

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple.

The function takes a pointer, not an iterator.

If you try to pass an iterator, then the function call *should be expected to fail*. Square peg, round hole.

---

#### Notes:

- The inverse is not the same, since a pointer can be considered a kind of iterator. Usually, a function taking an iterator can be passed a pointer.
- Your code may appear to compile in some very specific cases, due to implementation details. Don't let this fool you: it's still the wrong code to write!

Comment: As Alf points out, it is not guaranteed that it will fail, since the iterator *might* be a pointer. `vector` is the only standard container for which the iterator can be a pointer, though.

Comment: Occam's razor: "Entia non sunt multiplicanda *praeter necessitatem*" (my emphasis). In this case the simpler statement is false.

Comment: @Steve: "Lie to children", then.

Comment: Fair enough, although I think I still prefer Alf's explanation of the same thing.

Comment: @Steve: That's certainly your right! I choose to emphasise that iterators and pointers are not one and the same, rather than emphasising the slim band of scenarios where you can get away with pretending that they are.

Answer (score 1):

Because iterator is simply not a raw pointer(even though some underlying implementation could be pointer). The are many types of iterators: foward, bidirectional, random access. The closest iterator to pointer is a random access iterator like the one vector or deque has.

Answer (score 0):

The entire idea of an iterator is to enable flexible data storage that is not contiguously stored in memory. Incrementing an iterator could, for example, move to another "page" in an array that is stored as separate chunks of elements.

If you call a function that takes a pointer, the called function will simply do pointer arithmetic on the address when you increment it (so it won't follow links in a linked list for example).

Passing an iterator to a function that takes a pointer can't work. Dereferencing the first element then taking its address could work, only if you know for sure that the data in the container is stored contiguously. This would work for a vector, but it can't work if the container is a list.